Unable to login in ubuntu - nvme nvme0: Device not ready; aborting reset, CSTS=0x1
Sorry M newbie here, if this question has been asked earlier
I am unable to login in ubuntu system, there was no update no installation, all of sudden on restart it throwing me this error
OS: ubuntu 20.X(Sorry i dont exactly remember the number)
Issue : nvme nvme0: Device not ready; aborting reset, CSTS=0x1
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvmeOn1, secotr 10000214400 op oxo:(Read) flags phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Gave up rating for root file system device. etc
What I already tried:

Changing SATA config in bios to AHCI
Enable SGX in bios
Restart multiple times.

 Please help here.

I/O error almost always means the drive failed.

@ChanganAuto But the drive is visible in bios menu

Like almost all failed drives are. It takes a severe failure for it not being recognized.

Can i do something to validate it ? drive name is there in BIOS, Also should i try to repair the OS files somehow ? How can i try it

You can try from a live session but it probably will be a waste of your time. Meanwhile, and for the future, do not change UEFI settings unless you know you have to. Namely, the same drive mode used when installing and running is the one you should keep, not change unless it somehow changed and you know it. Everything else you tried is also irrelevant.
